# Why isn't my data sorting when there are multiples of dates?

Tags: excel, sorting, selection

I have a table of data in Excel. I am selecting the whole table and using the sort button at the top. I have tried sorting on Column B and Column C, but when I do the selection box around the table gets smaller and goes up to only select the top half of the table. What I interpret from this is that it chose a smaller range because it can't sort the full table. I feel like the problem might be because my data has **multiples of the date values in Column C.** How can I sort the data on Column B or Column C?

```
   A        B        C           D         E         F         G         H      
strings  integers  short dates  currency  currency  currency  currency  currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the row with the column titles. Under `Home`, `Sort and Filter`, click `Filter`.

Then click the down arrow that appears next to your column to play around with the sorting options (e.g. A->Z or Z->A).

This should work for column B (all integers) but might not for your 'multiple date values' in column C. You will want to convert these to one standard format first.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. When I try both sorting with the table selected and sorting without the table selected, it sorts the table _along with the tables under it_ and mixes all the data. Yikes.